Are certain usernames restricted in PTCGP?
When I registered for the first time in Pokémon Trading Cards Game Pocket, I wanted to use a username of 4 random letters, let's say "mzkp" (fake but something like that). And it didn't let me. So I thought "weird, it must be taken". And I removed the last letter, thus choosing "mzk". And it let me. And that has been my username until today that I changed it for something else.
Why didn't it let me have that "mzkp" username? That 4 letter combination I used at first only coincides with the name of an industrial managing system, that is trademarked (I've googled it). Would that be a reason why it would be a restricted username?
Can it be that trademarked words are restricted for usernames? If someone could try to set their usernames as "nike", "adidas" or "apple" and the game doesn't let them, then it's confirmed that trademarked words are restricted. If no one tries this in one month, by the time I can change my username again (can only change it every 30 days), I will try it myself, for science.
This is a follow-up question to this question: Are usernames unique in PTCGP?
In that question one user commented that a username can give an error if it has a trailing whitespace. However that couldn't be my error because I'm obsessed with trailing whitespaces in any software and I always delete them. Especially when submitting critical data like setting an username.

Since you commented that you knew about the trailing whitespace issue, you might mention that in this question.

It's worth noting that there's a list of censored words in the original games, so this might be the case with a foreign word

@ryanyuyu I just added it

Without knowing the exact username, it may be impossible to say. Could it be that you tried something like "mkms", which contains "KMS" (an acronym for "kill myself"—and also by complete coincidence "Knowledge Management System")?
